# Javascript proper way to .push array

Tags: javascript

How to use .push array in proper way using javascript?

my code

```js
let persons = [{
    "person1": "person1"
  },
  {
    "person1": "person1"
  }
]

let addPerson = []

addPersn.push({
  "person1": "person2"
})

let allPerson = persons.push(addPerson)
console.log(allPerson)
```

expected behavior

```
{
  "person1": "person1"
},
{
  "person1": "person1"
},
{
  "person1": "person1"
}
```

current result

```
3
```

How to use .push array in proper way using javascript?How to use .push array in proper way using javascript?

Comment: You do not need `addPersn.push`. You can directly push it to `persons`. However, assuming you are trying to create a setter, you can do this: `addPerson = (newPerson) => person.push(newPerson)`

Comment: [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array.

Comment: At step `persons.push(addPerson)` you are pushing an array with one person details `addPerson` in `persons` array. 
Thus at the end `persons` array will have `[Person, Person, [Person]]` that last element is not object but an array with one object.

Instead directly push the object in `persons` array. 
Do like this.
`let newPerson = { "person1": "person2" }` , then, `persons.push(newPerson)`

Comment: This this out https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/61c37f0e-41de-4bcb-b1ef-243d105adacf

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let persons = [
  {
    person1: "person1",
  },
  {
    person2: "person2",
  },
];

const newPerson = {
    person3: "person3",
}

persons.push(newPerson);
console.log(persons);
```